# Why do I change users when I login as root from terminal (fedora)? And why don't my changes to .bashrc & .bash_profile show up when I do?

Tags: linux, terminal, users

Okay, so when I log in as root in my terminal using `sudo`, `sudo -i`, or `su` I get:
`[dash@localhost IN => ~]$ su`
`Password`
`[root@localhost IN => /home/dash]$` (notice the `$` instead of `#`, this could be a mistake I made when editing `.bashrc` & `.bashprofile`)  (even though the last part of my `.bashrc` is `\$`)

Now, when I edit `.bashrc` & `.bash_profile` (as `root`)I see the changes only as long as I am `root`. When I close terminal and re-open it, the changes are gone. If I log in as `root`, however, the changes re-appear. Is it possible that there are 2 `.bashrc`s and 2 `.bash_profile`s? If so, does that mean that I changed the ones for the root user only?

On a different computer, I changed the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` as normal user (not `root`). The changes appeared only while I was NOT root. I heard that one of these two files is for normal terminal, and the other is for shells. If so, why did the changes appear only while I wasn't root, even though I put the same code in both files, rather than resorting to `if ~/etc/.bashrc...` ? (assuming that root is a shell)

Comment: Those files are store in the home folder which is unique for each user. `~/.bashrc` when logged in as root is not the same file as `~/.bashrc` when logged in as another user. `~` = the user’s home folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note that there are separate `.bashrc` file for each user including root.

In your first case when you used command `su` then you become root user whose current directory is `/home/dash`. If you do `echo $HOME` then you will find that it is `/root` and if you edit `.bashrc` file then you are editing this file in `/root` directory means that you are editing `.bashrc` file for root user. So these changes will appear only when you login as root not as normal user.

In second case when you edited file as normal user then the changes will appear to normal user only as you changed the files for  that user.

Comment: Is there a way to have root-like privileges without being root in terminal? That is, remaining logged in as your user, but still having elevated privileges?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the changes made to the files remain even if you are `root` in terminal, as long as you haven't logged out of the computer? Because I heard that one file is for when you are the same user in terminal as in the computer, and the other is for when you are in SSH, or logged in as other users.

Comment: @DashConroy you can use `sudo` to execute commands with `root` privilege while remaining logged as user

Comment: Okay, that's good, but that means I have to retype my password with every command. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: @DashConroy edit sudoers file using `visudo` command to make sudo passwordless but it is not recommended. Second solution is to increase the time limit of `sudo`. Google it and you will find.